# Solr Query Max Condition

Tags: solr, conditional-statements, solr4, solr-query-syntax, solarium

I am using solr 4.3.0 for my web site search. I want to do something using solr but when I query, I get an error. In my situation I have 40000 products, and I want to excludes 1500 products with query. This is the my query

```
-brand-slug:reebok OR -brand-slug:nike AND 
-skuCode:(01-117363 01-117364 01-117552 01-119131 01-119166 01-1J622 01-1J793 01-1M4434 01-1M9691 01-1Q279 01-1T405 01-1T865 01-2109830 01-2111116 01-2111186 01-21J625 01-21J794 01-21V019 01-2M9691 01-2M9696 01-33J793 01-519075 01-M4431 01-M7652 01-M9160 01-M9165 01-M9166 01-M9613 01-M9622 01-M9697 01200CY0001N00 01211SU0141M00 01212KU0009N00 01212KU0010N00 01212KU0025N00 01212KU0027N00 01212KU0038N00 01212KW0019N00 01212KW0020N00
....thousands of skuCodes)
```

If I put 670 skuCodes in their that will works good, but I use 1500 skuCodes is an error like

```
Solr HTTP error: OK (400)
```

How could I solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a night :) I solved my problem. Actually there was 2 problems in my system. First problem is in my tomcat server. I increase their request size with change maxHttpHeaderSize="65536". ( You could change your web server buffer size I changed my nginx conf). The other problem is about solr config. I got an error like 'too many boolean clauses'. If you get this error, you could change maxBooleanClauses in solrconfig.xml. After restart my tomcat server everything was ok.